# Best practice for managing automated .NET code execution

Tags: .net, architecture, scheduled-tasks, background-process

I'm designing a new software solution that includes a .NET web app hosted in IIS, from which users can trigger various pieces of functionality (again, has to be .NET code) to execute asynchronously in the background. I'm looking for appropriate technologies and architecture to use to accomplish this. Some important features that need to be supported are:

1. When the background functionality completes, the web application needs to be informed so that it can then inform the users on the browsers via websockets.
2. If the process executing the functionality crashes, on restart of that process it must be able to detect that the code did not complete and restart execution of that code
3. It must be possible to schedule the background functionality to start at some point in the future. Again, if the hosting process crashes, on restart it must become re-aware of the scheduled task so that it still successfully starts executing the functionality at the appropriate time.

If the background functionality is implemented by launching a new thread within the IIS instance, this makes #1 easy to implement. However, special code would have to be written to support #2 and #3 and it seems that many believe that hosting background functionality that needs to be able to recover from a crash or be scheduled in the future, inside the Web App, is bad practice.

Another option is to host the background process in a windows service. If so, what is the best way to solve #1, #2 and #3? This would all still require custom code - so is there software available that handles these requirements already?

Answer (score 2):

For this situation, hosting a web-app in IIS will only be 10% of the problem. HTTP is stateless and connectionless. So if a browser doesn't request anything, IIS (thus ASP.NET app) won't be able to respond back. A similar scenario that I faced was fixed as follows:

1. Host a scheduling Windows Service that manages #2 and #3.
2. Host a web-app that a user can access for latest data.

Now comes the important aspect of *data that needs to be shared between Web Service and Web App*. Simply use a Database that updates status corresponding to a given unique ID. When user requests update on that Unique ID in the Web application, it can easily fetch the update info and send it back to end user.

Comment: I'm intending to use websockets to update the connected browsers as soon as the WebApp knows about the change. I am intending to us a central DB, so would you suggest that the web app regularly polls the DB for changes, and forwards them on (via websockets) when it detects them?

Comment: It is important to know that Web Applications do not do anything unless requested. So if web page opened in web browser keeps on making polling requests to the web application, it can constantly keep on looking for data in DB and respond back. Just like an update shows up in Stackoverflow or a any new activity comes up. It is not pushed by the server, it is pulled by the web page in a browser window.

Comment: Hi Abhinav, my understanding of WebSocket technology is that its main feature is to keep an open connection between the browser and the web application, so that the web application can push information to the browser, without being specifically requested for it?

Comment: btw by WebSockets do you mean what is explained here -> http://www.paulbatum.com/2011/09/getting-started-with-websockets-in.html ? I honestly am not quite sure how that works. That would only change my answer to remove the Polling part.

Comment: @SimonGreen: If you are using WebSockets as explained on that link, you will still have to have a windows service for #2 and #3. #1 would be easier using WebSockets now.

Comment: Hi again, yes I agree - I think your answer and the other one below are basically the same. However I'm still interested to know if there is any proven software out there that provide a managed container for the code and handle #2 and #3 (and perhaps #1), before I start implementing it all myself

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be to separate the processing. i.e. start the processing from the website by putting the request into a queue (e.g. a database table) and use a separate worker service that polls that queue for tasks and only flag them as done when it succeeds in completing them (e.g. by putting the result in another table, or marking a *completed* column as true), then use a separate service/website to poll the results and notify users.

If the worker service crashes/fails it should not mark the queue items as completed, and whenever it restarts it can easily poll the uncompleted tasks queue again.

Comment: Hi Saeb, yes this all makes sense and is workable - but it sounds as though it's all code that would have to be written specially. Do you know if there is any proven code management software available that does this for me?

Comment: @SimonGreen, have a look at [Parallel .NET](http://codecanyon.net/item/parallelnet-background-task-scheduler/3721306), the [Azure WebJobs SDK](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/getting-started-with-windows-azure-webjobs) might also interest you.

Answer (score 1):

The ugly thing with IIS is, that IIS terminates its worker processes after a certain time. There are a view tricks to avoid this, but in fact if you want to have a reliable infrastructure, as mentioned you should place this code in a windows service and communicate via WCF with your web application.
You need a database in the background to store your tasks, so that they can be rescheduled after the computer is shut down or the service crashes.

We are building a framework for this kind of issues, but it isn't completely released yet. It allows to host queued/scheduled work in a windows service or Linux deamon (with MONO). It has the ability to maintain child processes, so if the child process crashes, it can be automatically restarted. Due to the fact that the parent process is a service or a deamon, it will be started and shut down with the computer. Instead of IIS hosting this processes are never automatically terminated and mustn't kept alive.

The parent / child process management is open source and available here:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/ChildProcesses/

http://childprocess.codeplex.com/

The Framework itself is called Crawler-Lib Framework, but currently only the workflow engine is released. The services, module management, WCF modules,  database connectors and so on will be released soon. It can be found here:

http://www.crawler-lib.net/

Comment: Thanks for the links Thomas, I'll take a look

Comment: You would do the same for me. Because this is all work in progress and not yet released, please contact me if you find it interesting.